# libgdx onto existing IOS and Android App, Feasiblity and App Size

Tags: libgdx, ios, spritekit

I am an IOS developer, my client has an existing app which they want to add some simple microgames onto. The main requirement is that the app size footprint is as small as possible.

I suggested that Spritekit would give the smallest footprint but they want a cross-platform solution.

My initial reading on libgdx is that is is difficult to implement on IOS.

So before I begin learning libgdx I would like to know whether it is feasible to implement on top of an existing IOS app and whether this is the best solution for a small app size footprint

Comment: Libgdx is written in Java. I'd barely consider this option for your purpose

Comment: Why is the language it is written in a factor? Which options do you think would perform better?

Comment: iOS doesn't support Java language natively, thus it will at least bring some transpiling overhead. Why not consider C++/Objective-C frameworks like Cocos2D?

Comment: We have looked at Cocos2D, the build size is coming in at the high end, perhaps we can find a way to reduce this. The reverse argument can be made for Android. We are in a feasibility phase at the moment.